# Angular 4 - ngFor does not rerender whole DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, performance

I'm just checking the `trackBy` option for the `*ngFor` . In most of the examples that are available on the internet, it shows that if you don't use `trackBy` option by default, it rerenders the whole DOM. For example, if we have a table and 3 rows, which are generated with `ngFor`, after adding another row, in the console you can see that all 4 rows are regenerated. If you use the `trackBy`, it would render only the 4th row, and the previous 3 rows would stay as is.

But the confusing part comes in here. I tried to reproduce the example with the table rows with Angular 4, and when I try to add new row with just `ngFor` (without using `trackBy`), it magically does not re-render whole DOM for me, but exactly re-renders just the last row. If I add the trackBy function, it does not change the way how the DOM is re-rendered.

Just wondering, if they have updated it at some time of point and now the `ngFor` is more efficient, or am I missing something?

Example code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-igjyci?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Example gif: [GIF in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfhth.gif)

Comment: Add some code here.

Comment: Will add example gif, where you can see it in action and code in a minute.

Comment: Added gif and example code. As you can see the console shows that the only thing changed on the DOM is the new line added. And the code does not have trackBy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only push a new element to the Array the dom will not be changed, because the identities of the previous elements remain the same. Only for example if you redo the whole array (even with the same values) will the DOM change. TrackBy just adds the ability to identify an object by a different method. Have a look at the link below for a full explanation.

https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#change-propagation

Comment: So in my example, if I would change the list to input fields, which references to an object, and if I change the text, would it re-render the whole DOM?

Comment: No. It identifies an object by its signature, if you change anything in that object itself the li (in this case) is not changed. Only if you make a new object and replace the old one with the new one, does angular change the li element. With trackBy you add the ability to identify an object by something else like example the id of the dataset.

Comment: Do you mind updating my above example to show the case, where it does update all li elements? Or provide a code here, since it's still a bit unclear.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tcm6ay?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html